# Dynamic programming: Algorithm to solve the following?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I have recently completed the following interview exercise:

'A robot can be programmed to run "a", "b", "c"... "n" kilometers and it takes t<sub>a</sub>, t<sub>b</sub>, t<sub>c</sub>... t<sub>n</sub> minutes, respectively. Once it runs to programmed kilometers, it must be turned off for "m" minutes.

After "m" minutes it can again be programmed to run for a further "a", "b", "c"... "n" kilometers.

How would you program this robot to go an exact number of kilometers in the minimum amount of time?'

I thought it was a variation of the unbounded [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems) problem, in which the size would be the number of kilometers and the value, the time needed to complete each stretch. The main difference is that we need to minimise, rather than maximise, the value. So I used the equivalent of the following solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem
in which I select the minimum.

Finally, because we need an exact solution (if there is one), over the map constructed by the algorithm for all the different distances, I iterated through each and trough each robot's programmed distance to find the exact distance and minimum time among those.

I think the pause the robot takes between runs is a bit of a red herring and you just need to include it in your calculations, but it does not affect the approach taken.

I am probably wrong, because I failed the test. I don't have any other feedback as to the expected solution.

Edit: maybe I wasn't wrong after all and I failed for different reasons. I just wanted to validate my approach to this problem.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Sets.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

public final class Robot {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger (Robot.class);

    private Set<ProgrammedRun> programmedRuns;
    private int pause;
    private int totalDistance;

    private Robot () {
        //don't expose default constructor & prevent subclassing 
    }


    private Robot (int[] programmedDistances, int[] timesPerDistance, int pause, int totalDistance) {

        this.programmedRuns = newHashSet ();
        for (int i = 0; i < programmedDistances.length; i++) {
            this.programmedRuns.add (new ProgrammedRun (programmedDistances [i], timesPerDistance [i] ) );
        }
        this.pause = pause;
        this.totalDistance = totalDistance;
    }


    public static Robot create (int[] programmedDistances, int[] timesPerDistance, int pause, int totalDistance) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument (programmedDistances.length == timesPerDistance.length);
        Preconditions.checkArgument (pause >= 0);
        Preconditions.checkArgument (totalDistance >= 0);
        return new Robot (programmedDistances, timesPerDistance, pause, totalDistance);
    }

    /**
     * @returns null if no strategy was found. An empty map if distance is zero. A
     * map with the programmed runs as keys and number of time they need to be run
     * as value.  
     * 
     */
    Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> calculateOptimalStrategy () {

        //for efficiency, consider this case first
        if (this.totalDistance == 0) {
            return Maps.newHashMap ();
        }

        //list of solutions for different distances. Element "i" of the list is the best set of runs that cover at least "i" kilometers
        List <Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer>> runsForDistances = Lists.newArrayList();

        //special case i = 0 -> empty map (no runs needed)
        runsForDistances.add (new HashMap<ProgrammedRun, Integer> () );

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalDistance; i++) {
            Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> map = new HashMap<ProgrammedRun, Integer> ();
            int minimumTime = -1;
            for (ProgrammedRun pr : programmedRuns) {
                int distance = Math.max (0, i - pr.getDistance ());
                int time = getTotalTime (runsForDistances.get (distance) ) + pause + pr.getTime();
                if (minimumTime < 0 || time < minimumTime) {
                    minimumTime = time;
                    //new minimum found
                    map = new HashMap<ProgrammedRun, Integer> ();
                    map.putAll(runsForDistances.get (distance) );

                    //increase count
                    Integer num = map.get (pr);
                    if (num == null) num = Integer.valueOf (1);
                    else num++;

                    //update map
                    map.put (pr, num);
                }
            }
            runsForDistances.add (map );
        }

        //last step: calculate the combination with exact distance

        int minimumTime2 = -1;
        int bestIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalDistance; i++) {
            if (getTotalDistance (runsForDistances.get (i) ) == this.totalDistance ) {
                int time = getTotalTime (runsForDistances.get (i) );
                if (time > 0) time -= pause;
                if (minimumTime2 < 0 || time < minimumTime2 ) {
                    minimumTime2 = time;
                    bestIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }

        //if solution found

        if (bestIndex != -1) {
            return runsForDistances.get (bestIndex);
        }

        //try all combinations, since none of the existing maps run for the exact distance
        List <Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer>> exactRuns = Lists.newArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= totalDistance; i++) {
            int distance = getTotalDistance (runsForDistances.get (i) );
            for (ProgrammedRun pr : programmedRuns) {
                //solution found
                if (distance + pr.getDistance() == this.totalDistance ) {
                    Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> map = new HashMap<ProgrammedRun, Integer> ();
                    map.putAll (runsForDistances.get (i));

                    //increase count
                    Integer num = map.get (pr);
                    if (num == null) num = Integer.valueOf (1);
                    else num++;

                    //update map
                    map.put (pr, num);

                    exactRuns.add (map);
                }
            }
        }

        if (exactRuns.isEmpty()) return null;

        //finally return the map with the best time
        minimumTime2 = -1;
        Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> bestMap = null;

        for (Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> m : exactRuns) {
            int time = getTotalTime (m);
            if (time > 0) time -= pause; //remove last pause
            if (minimumTime2 < 0 || time < minimumTime2 ) {
                minimumTime2 = time;
                bestMap = m;
            }
        }

        return bestMap;
    }

    private int getTotalTime (Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> runs) {
        int time = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<ProgrammedRun, Integer> runEntry : runs.entrySet()) {
            time += runEntry.getValue () * runEntry.getKey().getTime ();
            //add pauses
            time += this.pause * runEntry.getValue ();
        }
        return time;
    }

    private int getTotalDistance (Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> runs) {
        int distance = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<ProgrammedRun, Integer> runEntry : runs.entrySet()) {
            distance += runEntry.getValue() * runEntry.getKey().getDistance ();
        }
        return distance;
    }

    class ProgrammedRun {
        private int distance;
        private int time;
        private transient float speed;

        ProgrammedRun (int distance, int time) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.time = time;
            this.speed = (float) distance / time;
        }

        @Override public String toString () {
            return "(distance =" + distance + "; time=" + time + ")";
        }

        @Override public boolean equals (Object other) {
            return other instanceof ProgrammedRun 
                && this.distance == ((ProgrammedRun)other).distance 
                && this.time == ((ProgrammedRun)other).time;
        }

        @Override public int hashCode () {
            return Objects.hashCode (Integer.valueOf (this.distance), Integer.valueOf (this.time));
        }

        int getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        int getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        float getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }
    }

}


public class Main {

    /* Input variables for the robot */

    private static int [] programmedDistances = {1, 2, 3, 5, 10}; //in kilometers
    private static int [] timesPerDistance = {10, 5, 3, 2, 1}; //in minutes

    private static int pause = 2; //in minutes

    private static int totalDistance = 41; //in kilometers

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Robot r = Robot.create (programmedDistances, timesPerDistance, pause, totalDistance);

        Map<ProgrammedRun, Integer> strategy = r.calculateOptimalStrategy ();

        if (strategy == null) {
            System.out.println ("No strategy that matches the conditions was found");
        } else if (strategy.isEmpty ()) {
            System.out.println ("No need to run; distance is zero");
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Strategy found:");
            System.out.println (strategy);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution seems OK if robot can run only in one direction. If it can run backwards, just add "negative distances" to the knapsack problem. If it can run anywhere in 2D space, simple greedy algorithm will be the best.

Comment: I have simplified the description but it can only go forward and on a line. I thought of a greedy approach though, it just didn't seem to have better O(n) -potentially having to traverse the whole tree to find an exact solution in the worst case-, but that was just my intuition talking with limited time constraints. I might be wrong :)

Comment: Then, may be, the "a", "b", "c"... "n" kilometers are some sort of floating point numbers or very big relatively prime integer numbers. In this case DP is not applicable and branch-and-cut algorithm shoult be used. By the way, greedy approach (though not optimal for this task) is always O(N) (or O(N log N) to pre-sort values).

Comment: by `ta` you mean \t_a not t*a yes?

Comment: How did you include m in your calculations?

Comment: Yes, Saeed, "ta" it's just a constant, I'm not multiplying.

Comment: Wolfram, the solution for knapsack if defined recursively. If you have a set of distances in [0,D] and for each, a group of "runs" that cover or surpasses that distance, then for D+1 you just calculate the value (the time) using the values in [0,D] + one of the robot's programmed run time +  the pause. In the last step, to calculate the best time for an exact distance you have to subtract the pause time, so the number of pauses is the number of "runs" - 1. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Jubbat: why don't you construct a couple of simple short test cases and solve them by hand? Then you can step through your code and find the problem.

Comment: Pause time "m" appears to be a constant not related to speed or distance so I don't think you can easily ignore it. Suppose "m" is large - the number of legs in the trip then becomes important. A "high speed" many leg trip could loose over a "low speed" fewer leg trip due to the accumulated "m" values.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I did get the question right. For examples, the distances could be (1, 7, 9) km, the time for these (2, 7, 8) minutes, the distance to solve 30km. Now I could program the robot to run (1+7+9)=17km in 17 minutes, pause 2 minutes, plus (1+9)km  in 10 more minutes=29 minutes (km: 27) + 3x 1km in 3x(2+2)m? If the 2m-penalty has to be counted after every distance, you could just increase the time in the mapped interval (2,7,8)=>(4,9,10) and substract 2 minutes in the end, because after reaching the finish line, there is no need to wait?

Comment: @Groo strictly speaking there is no problem with my code as far as I can see, in any case the question is different

Comment: @NealB I'm not ignoring pauses. They are very well account for in the time calculation

Comment: @user unknown yes, that would be a perfectly good instance of the problem

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. You stated: *I just wanted to validate my approach to this problem*. I believe most answers agree: **yes, dynamic programming is the way to go**. But since you haven't posted your actual code, there is not much benefit from this thread IMHO.

Comment: @Groo It's very clear what I am asking. And I find it very hard to see the point of adding the code in order to answer my question. Having said that, I have just graciously added my code, for your benefit, anonymous dweller of the internets and for whoever might be interested in implementing this. -- But really, I'm dumbfounded. If I ask "I have such and such problem and I have solved it using the knapsack algorithm but minimising the value, is this a good approach?" how is it not clear?

Comment: I probably got your question wrong then. I got this feeling from your comments on the answers below (to @Saeed's answer describing dynamic programming) and the fact that at that time you didn't accept the now-accepted answer. So I just wasn't sure what you were actually looking for.

Comment: @Groo Never mind. Sorry I was unnecessarily blunt in my comment. I should have replied in a different way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplifying slightly, let t<sub>i</sub> be the time (including downtime) that it takes the robot to run distance d<sub>i</sub>. Assume that t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub> ≤ … ≤ t<sub>n</sub>/d<sub>n</sub>. If t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub> is significantly smaller than t<sub>2</sub>/d<sub>2</sub> and d<sub>1</sub> and the total distance D to be run are large, then branch and bound likely outperforms dynamic programming. Branch and bound solves the integer programming formulation

minimize ∑<sub>i</sub> t<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>
subject to
∑<sub>i</sub> d<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub> = D
∀i x<sub>i</sub> ∈ **N**

by using the value of the relaxation where x<sub>i</sub> can be any nonnegative real as a guide. The latter is easily verified to be at most (t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub>)D, by setting x<sub>1</sub> to D/d<sub>1</sub> and ∀i ≠ 1 x<sub>i</sub> = 0, and at least (t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub>)D, by setting the sole variable of the dual program to t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub>. Solving the relaxation is the *bound* step; every integer solution is a fractional solution, so the best integer solution requires time at least (t<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>1</sub>)D.

The *branch step* takes one integer program and splits it in two whose solutions, taken together, cover the entire solution space of the original. In this case, one piece could have the extra constraint x<sub>1</sub> = 0 and the other could have the extra constraint x<sub>1</sub> ≥ 1. It might look as though this would create subproblems with side constraints, but in fact, we can just delete the first move, or decrease D by d<sub>1</sub> and add the constant t<sub>1</sub> to the objective. Another option for branching is to add either the constraint x<sub>i</sub> = ⌊D/d<sub>i</sub>⌋ or x<sub>i</sub> ≤ ⌊D/d<sub>i</sub>⌋ - 1, which requires generalizing to upper bounds on the number of repetitions of each move.

The main loop of branch and bound selects one of a collection of subproblems, branches, computes bounds for the two subproblems, and puts them back into the collection. The efficiency over brute force comes from the fact that, when we have a solution with a particular value, every subproblem whose relaxed value is at least that much can be thrown away. Once the collection is emptied this way, we have the optimal solution.

Hybrids of branch and bound and dynamic programming are possible, for example, computing optimal solutions for small D via DP and using those values instead of branching on subproblems that have been solved.

Comment: Thanks. My knowledge of this is a bit rusty, but this seems like a suitable alternative solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Create array of size m and for 0 to m( m is your distance) do:

> a[i] = infinite;
>
> a[0] = 0;
>
> a[i] = min{min{a[i-j] + t<sub>j</sub> + m for all **j** in possible kilometers of robot. and **j≠i**} , **t<sub>i</sub>** if **i** is in possible moves of robot}

a[m] is lowest possible value. Also you can have array like `b` to save `a[i]`s selection. Also if a[m] == infinite means it's not possible.

**Edit:** we can solve it in another way by creating a digraph, again our graph is dependent to `m` length of path, graph has nodes labeled {0..m}, now start from node 0 connect it to all possible nodes; means if you have a kilometer `i` you can connect 0 and v<sub>i</sub> with weight t<sub>i</sub>, except for node 0->x, for all other nodes you should connect node i->j with weight **t<sub>j-i</sub> + m** for j>i and j-i is available in input kilometers. now you should find shortest path from v<sub>0</sub> to v<sub>n</sub>. but this algorithm still is O(nm).

Comment: Yes, Saeed that's pretty much my algorithm. I see you have understood it. I think I am asking something different ie. How would you solve this, is this a good solution, etc

Comment: If this is solution to your problem I think is good, currently I don't know how to reduce it to npc problems, but I guess your problem is npc, also I couldn't understand you have one robot or more than one? and if more than one, they can have collision or not.

Answer (score 0):

Let G be the desired distance run.

Let n be the longest possible distance run without pause.

Let L = G / n (Integer arithmetic, discard fraction part)

Let R = G mod n (ie. The remainder from the above division)

Make the robot run it's longest distance (ie. n) L times, and then whichever distance (a, b, c, etc.) is greater than R by the least amount (ie the smallest available distance that is equal to or greater than R)

Either I understood the problem wrong, or you're all over thinking it

Comment: But you should minimise time. I know it doesn´t make much sense, but in this problem you could have a programmed run of 10 km in 1m and another of 1km in 10m. -- Now, if you sort by speed instead, that would be a greedy approach. I am still unsure if it has better or worse O(n) time for the average and worst case. And to be completely honest it is even hard for me to visualise why the knapsack problem is NP Complete in the first place

Comment: This is definitely not correct. Simple example: total distance=10, available unit distances =6,5,1. You're doing 6,1,1,1,1 while optimal is clearly 5,5. And I'm not even taking time under consideration!

Comment: @Marcin Nope: 6, 5. 1 is not greater than or equal to R. I agree that the optimum solution would be 5, 5 though.

Comment: @Jubbat Sorry, I didn't realise that the time wasn't proportional to distance travelled.

Comment: @AaronJLang - perhaps I misread "How would you program this robot to go a exact number of kilometers in the minimum amount of time?" 6+5 != 10...

Comment: @Aaron J Lang It's okay, the truth is that it doesn't make sense, but it's like that!

Answer (score 0):

I am a big believer in showing instead of telling. Here is a program that may be doing what you are looking for. Let me know if it satisfies your question. Simply copy, paste, and run the program. You should of course test with your own data set.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Speed {
/***
 *
 * @param distance
 * @param sprints ={{A,Ta},{B,Tb},{C,Tc}, ..., {N,Tn}}
 */
public static int getFastestTime(int distance, int[][] sprints){
    long[] minTime = new long[distance+1];//distance from 0 to distance
    Arrays.fill(minTime,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    minTime[0]=0;//key=distance; value=time
    for(int[] speed: sprints)
        for(int d=1; d<minTime.length; d++)
            if(d>=speed[0] && minTime[d] > minTime[d-speed[0]]+speed[1])
                minTime[d]=minTime[d-speed[0]]+speed[1];
    return (int)minTime[distance];
}//

public static void main(String... args){
    //sprints ={{A,Ta},{B,Tb},{C,Tc}, ..., {N,Tn}}
    int[][] sprints={{3,2},{5,3},{7,5}};
    int distance = 21;
    System.out.println(getFastestTime(distance,sprints));
}
}
```